# bootsector eject cd rom

Tags: assembly, bootloader

Im trying to create bootloader that is able to eject CD-ROM. I found this, but doesn't work for me:

```
mov cx,0x0
unlock:
    mov ah,0x45
    mov al,0x01
    mov dl,cl
    int 0x13
eject:
    mov ah,0x46
    mov al,0x0
    mov dl,cl
    int 0x13
cmp ah,0xb1
je unlock
inc cl
jnz unlock
mov ax,0x4c00
int 21h
```

this is print code that I mentioned in one comment:

```
print:
    lodsb
    or al,al
    jz .done
    mov ah,0x0E
    int 0x10
    jmp print
.done:
    ret

print1:
    mov si,m1
    call print
    ret
```

Comment: Although not the answer you would be hoping for, this is easier said than done (ejecting a drive). You'll likely have to write code to detect the CD drive and then send commands to the ATAPI interface. The answer provided for a similar question gives you some links to the ATAPI interface and ATA in general. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382750/3857942

Comment: And looking at your code you are using `int 21h` with ax being `4c00`. That is a DOS interrupt and in particular it stops the current program from running and returns back to DOS. If you are writing a bootloader `int 21h` is not available to you unless DOS is booted. If this is in your boot loader it won't work as expected.